# Looking for an advanced PDF comparison software

Tags: pdf

For a work assignment I have to read through 600-1000 page pdfs and form a general opinion on how similar they are (the extent to which the company putting them out is using 'boilerplate' formats).

I've used Adobe XI Pro DC's comparator software, which can compare two PDFs and highlight the parts that are different or changed. What I'll do is look through the comparison PDF, and any part that isn't highlighted I'll know is the exact same in both PDFs.

The problem with this software is that if the similar portions/strings are very far apart from each other in terms of page count (ex: if the relevant section is on page 100 of the first PDF but page 25 on the second PDF), this comparison software isn't going to catch it.

My ideal PDF comparator software would highlight only sections/paragraphs/strings in the first PDF that cannot be found ANYWHERE in the second PDF. Any section/string/paragraph which is also found in the second PDF, no matter how far apart in terms of page count, would stay unhighlighted.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: As you are primaryly interested in text comparison, you might consider exporting as text, and then look for text comparison tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check [xdocdiff](http://freemind.s57.xrea.com/xdocdiff/e/) project (open-source that you may adapt to your needs) and maybe some of [these diff tools](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-diff.html) recommended in TortoiseSVN documentation (open-source and closed source).